# Form - CSS / Required attribute active style

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form on a website with input with the required attribute.

When the required attribute is actived on Firefox (when user do't fill correcty the form), there is a kind of red border on my input.

I would like to know how can I change that ? I can I manipulate the style of the required effect when it is activated ?

Thanks for you answers !

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: you can use the inline code editor from stackoverflow or use https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by `:valid` and `:invalid` Pseudo class.

```css
 input:valid {
      border: 1px solid green;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    input:invalid {
      border: 1px solid red;
      outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" required />
```

Comment: Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) for browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You use two pseudo-selectors in combination: `:required:invalid` and `:required:valid`

For example:

`input[type=text]:required:invalid { border-color: red; }`